# How to permanently set Wi-Fi "power management" flag to off?

Tags: wireless, power-management

I've installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04, and it had problems with wireless network - it was terribly slow. Fortunately, I managed to find the problem: power management.

`sudo iwconfig`

```
wlp0s20f3 IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"SmellsLikeWireless"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 11:A1:B1:01:D1:11   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2640   Missed beacon:0
```

The fix:
`sudo iwconfig wlp0s20f3 power off`

and now the power management flag is set to off:

`Power Management:off`

and Wi-Fi speed is great.

However, when the laptop goes to sleep, the power management flag is again set to `on`. How do I permanently set it to `off`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your current power save state:

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*.conf
```

Unless it has been previously changed, it should read:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

In this context, 3 indicates that the Network Manager *will* use power saving. Let's change it to 2, indicating that the system *will not* use power saving. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: Before I try: what does the first line do?

Comment: @Danijel it replaces `2` with `3` in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` files.

Comment: @chili555 Are you sure it won't replace something wrong? ;-)

Comment: Quite sure. It simply tells Network Manager to NOT use power saving. I ran it earlier and it works perfectly on my system. In the unlikely event that it doesn't work for you, it may be easily reversed.

Comment: @chili555 This is not a criticism, but I didn't know that there can't be another `3` ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 Please see my edit above and check for yourself. This technique has been in use successfully for several years.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of editing the files and restarting NetworkManager, you can also use nmcli to do this:

```
nmcli connection modify _ssid_ wifi.powersave 2
```